# Ошибка: выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++, ооп

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(Point _pLeftUp, Point _pRightDown)
    : m_pLU(_pLeftUp), m_pRD(_pRightDown)
{
    m_pLD.m_x = m_pLU.m_x; //<-- Error!

    if (m_pRD.m_x < m_pLU.m_x || m_pLU.m_y < m_pRD.m_y)
        throw std::logic_error("Invalid rectangle coordinates");
}
```

`m_pLD`, `m_pLU`, `m_pRD`, `m_pRU` — это структуры на углы четыреугольника. `Point` и `Rectangle` имеют спецификатор доступа `private`. `Const` возле `m_pLD`, `m_pLU`, `m_pRD` и `m_pRU` не стоит.

Comment: что такое m_pLD ?

Comment: Как у вас описаны типы Point и Rectangle?

Comment: Вангую, что там `const Point m_pLD, m_pLU`

Comment: @Sergey вносите изменения в вопрос через ссылку [edit] под вопросом. В комментариях существенный части писать не стоит.

Comment: Приводите полные определения `Point` и `Rectangle`. Что такое `m_x`?